# Fading image after specific amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want my page to open with a picture and I want that picture to fade-out 10 seconds after. Which way is the best way I can do it ? Is there any way I can do it with Css3 ?

Comment: What's the mark-up for the page? And what've you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So long as you've given the element to fade out an `id` (or have some way to reference it from JavaScript):

```
window.setTimeout(
    function(){
        $('#pictureID').fadeOut('slow');
    },10000);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Je3wB/).

I'm assuming that you're using the image as a splash screen, of sorts? If so, then you can use `position: absolute` to position that image over the content of the page, and then fade out to reveal the contents below ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Je3wB/1/)).

If, however, you also want the user to be able to `hover` over the image to hold it in place then the following could be used (the above, but with a couple of amendments):

```
var fadeAnim = window.setTimeout(
    function(){
        $('#i').fadeOut('slow');
    },10000);

$('#i').hover(
    function(){
        window.clearTimeout(fadeAnim);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Je3wB/6/).

References:

- JavaScript (from the [Mozilla Developer Network's JavaScript resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)):

  - [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).
  - [`window.clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout).
- jQuery (from the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)):

  - [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

Answer (score 4):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.imgClass').fadeOut('slow')
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Javascript to do that. You can cross Javascript (our jQuery) with CSS3 but for cross-browser issue you'd better do it in full jquery. To do so, you can use load(), delay() and fadeOut().

Try :

```
$('#yourImg').ready(function(){
$(this).delay(10000).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout()` to delay the start of the fade, and then you can fade it out using either jquery(or another javascript library such as mootools) or you can add a class to the element and have it transition using a css3 transition. Since the jQuery version has already been posted, i'll post the css3 version. http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/3Vnt7/

CSS:

```
#demo {
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:opacity 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    border: 4px solid green;
    background-color: #ededed;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;

}
.hidden {
    opacity: 0.0;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('demo').className = "hidden"; 
},10000);
```